# How to use node_modules from the View with Laravel?

Tags: node.js, laravel, laravel-blade

I installed Material Design Icons with `npm install mdi --save` and I am trying from my view access this mdi folder. I am trying to use `../node_modules/mdi/css/materialdesignicons.min.css` but this is not working. I know that If I move the files do public I will get them, but this just make no sense. I think there is a way to get those modules even from the View file. What am I missing? Thankss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to move the required files to public. Here's why:

You are serving your Laravel app to the world with a web server (maybe Apache, maybe Nginx, maybe something else). Web servers **by design** serve only certain files - you do not want a web server providing any old file from your server to clients all over the internet. So, the web server is locked down to prevent access to all of the files on the server except those you want to give access to. That's why we put files in a certain folder (`/var/www` for Apache).

Somewhere on your server you might have that CSS file in a `node_modules` directory somewhere. The web server is going to ignore that directory because it is probably not in the directory from which it serves file. To make sure that file is available to your clients, you will need to move it.

Comment: Ohhhh, It makes a lot of sense. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Kryten is right. i prefer to serve all my files from the public rather than node_modules during production